# Resuming an Android app Activity with launchmode singleTask

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-lifecycle

#### Overview

I have an Android app with two activities:

- Activity A is an onboarding with intent-filter as MAIN, LAUNCHER and launchmode singleTask
- Activity B is a WebView that took data from Activity A

On first load a user will onboard and then `startActivity()` takes them to Activity B with a `finish()`.  ActivityB is technically the main activity view I want the user to be seeing from now on for the rest of the future.  I do set preferences so that Activity A will segue to B on the next close/open.

#### Behavior

When the app is backgrounded and then resumed, Activity B refreshes the webpage each time.  It appears the app goes through Activity A and then B which has a `loadUrl()`.  Why does `singleTask` run through the entire app?

Not setting launchMode or using singleInstance results in Activity A being properly ignored and staying on Activity B.   However I was using singleTask because of an unrelated Branch.io setup.

Some info on this: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Related:
[Android:Understanding how does an activity start when application launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403472/androidunderstanding-how-does-an-activity-start-when-application-launches)

Comment: >But my console log still seems to show that Activity A does get run through but NOT Activity B.
Can you explain this?

Comment: Sorry to clarify: `singleTask` Results in both activities code being re-executed on resume. `singleInstance` Results in Activity A being executed but not Activity B

Comment: are you trying to launch your app from launcher?

Comment: From launcher, and upon app resume